# Material-ui Autocomplete warning The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am working with React and material-ui.. I just realize i have a warning with the Autocomplete component when i try to submit the form, so i tried to do something really basic just like in the documentation:

```
let Form = props => {

  return(
        <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
            <Autocomplete
                id="combo-box-demo"
                options={[{id:1,name:"test"},{id:2, name:"test2"}]}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                style={{ width: 300 }}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
            />
```

and when i try to submit the form i get the following error:

Material-UI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
None of the options match with `{"id":1,"name":"test"}`.
You can use the `getOptionSelected` prop to customize the equality test.

I also realize that if i set the options in the state of the component there is no warning (just when they are set like a constant). So i wonder if some of you have any idea of this behavior? thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Basically the reason why you get the warning is a default implementation of `getOptionSelected` in version 4.x.x:

```js
 getOptionSelected = (option, value) => option === value
```

In your case, selecting a value the following comparison happens:

```
// option === value:
{id:1, name:"test"} === {id:1, name:"test"} // false
```

Obviously, it can be `true` in some circumstances. In this particular case, it's `false` because of objects pointing to the different instances.

**Solution!** You have to overwrite `getOptionSelected` implementation:

```
<Autocomplete
 getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
 ...otherProps
/>
```

**[Update]**
Note, in version 5.x.x the prop was renamed:

```
-  getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
+  isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
```

Comment: https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/

with version 5 of MUI, getOptionSelected has been renamed to isOptionEqualToValue

Comment: Thanks. But what if my autocomplete fetches the options from backend, and none of the new options match the old value?

Comment: Could I just return true? Since I'm fetching the values from the backend, and it means the value is correct?

Comment: @OttoGutierrez i have the same case. how did you solve this ? i don't see the problem on just set the value of `isOptionEqualToValue` to true so far

Comment: If is something async coming from the server, you could see if the options are loading still, to return true. Because otherwise, it will try to search through an empty list for a seleciton.

Comment: +  isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
this fixed the issue I had wrapping formik + material ui together - placed it under the {...field} param

Comment: But what if I want no option to be selected ? It's totally fine that no option matches the selected state. I still want the component to be controlled, just unselected. That doesn't seem to be possible or what?

Answer (score 32):

version 5.0

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.value === value.value}
```

Answer (score 26):

Also when you want to build a searcher where value you write is not necesary the same as the options you can set `freeSolo` to true and the warning will disapear

Comment: This answer should have way more focus than it has. Was building a async autocomplete (with a request to API on change) and this was the only way to fix this warning

Comment: To follow up on this, setting `freeSolo` will remove the pop-up button (the drop-down arrow on the right side of the Autocomplete component). To retain this button, you should also add `forcePopupIcon={true}`.

Answer (score 8):

This Worked,

```
getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.value === value.value}
```

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18514#issuecomment-606854194

Answer (score 8):

Following up on [elVengadors Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72732562/1720829):

When you want to build a searcher where the value you type in the box (the `inputValue`) is not necessarily one of the provided options you can set `freeSolo` to true.

**This will stop the warning message from being displayed.**

The need for this might arise if you are creating a component that allows for asynchronous querying of an API. This would cause the value of `options` to change based on the response from the API, but options that have already been selected before changing the `inputValue` to query the API may not be included in this new list of options.

---

In the [Autocomplete Component Documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/), `freeSolo` is described as:

> If true, the Autocomplete is free solo, meaning that the user input is not bound to provided options.

---

#### Bonus

Setting `freeSolo` to `true` will remove the pop-up button (the drop-down arrow on the right side of the Autocomplete component). To retain this button, you should also add `forcePopupIcon={true}`.

Comment: What if I want to remove the warning but don't want to enable free solo functionality? I.E, allow the user only to pick values from the changing options array

Answer (score 0):

```
const CustomAutocomplete = ({
  value,
  onChange,
  options,
  name,
  label,
  error,
  inputRef,
  onBlur,
}) => {
  const acValue = useMemo(() => {
    return options.find((option) => option.value === value);
  }, [options, value]);
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      value={acValue}
      disablePortal
      onChange={(e, v) => {
        onChange(v?.value);
      }}
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(o) => {
        return o.title;
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <UnControlledTextField
          {...params}
          fullWidth
          onBlur={onBlur}
          inputRef={inputRef}
          name={name}
          label={label}
          error={error}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

In my case, I am using custom options and storing only the value in form data

I am keeping options as

```
{ title, value }
```

And `onChange` only stores `value` part of the option

Answer (score 0):

MUI Autocomplete searchable component + RFA (react From Hook). 
SET default value to null , then you will get rid of the warning .

```html
 <RHFAutocomplete
            name="responsible"
            options={responsibles.map((r) => ({ _id: r._id, label: r.name }))}
            label="Responsable magasin"
            onValueChanges={(value) => setResponsibleFilter(value)}
          />
```

in my Autocomplete component I added a function props to get input value called `onValueChanges`

```html
 <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <Autocomplete
          {...field}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => setValue(name, newValue, { shouldValidate: true })}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              label={`${translate(label)}`}
              error={!!error}
              onChange={(e) => onValueChanges ? onValueChanges(e.target.value) : {}}
              helperText={error ? error?.message : helperText}
              {...params}
            />
          )}
          {...other}
        />
      )}
    />
```

Here is the final output.
[mui autocomplete searchable component + RFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOcxT.png)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(options, value) => options.valueOf === value.valueOf}
```

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for contributing an answer. This is just a note to help you improve your answers. To help future users better understand your answer please provide an explanation with your code block. For example, you could explain why your solution works, or how your approach is different from other answers.

Answer (score -1):

for whoever also struggles with the error/warning `useAutocomplete.js:210  MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid. None of the options match with "". You can use the` isOptionEqualToValue `prop to customize the equality test`

and struggles with the `defaultValue` prop.

make sure you dont pass empty string to your autocomplete variable value as default when initializing the hook.

```js
  const expenseForm = useForm<ExpenseFormInput>({
    defaultValues: {
      autocompleteval: '',
    },
  });
```

it would override and `defaultValue` value you passed to the component and would trigger annoying mui warning.

Answer (score -7):

I think you should not use `<form>` to wrap `AutoComplete` component. You should set value for `AutoComplete` and use a function to handle on click button to submit.
Try this:

```js
let Form = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({})
  
  const handleOnSubmit = (value) => {
    setValue(value)
    ...
  }

  return(
        <div>
            <Autocomplete
                id="combo-box-demo"
                value={value}
                options={[{id:1,name:"test"},{id:2, name:"test2"}]}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                style={{ width: 300 }}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
            />
            <Button onClick={() => handleOnSubmit(value)}>Submit</Button>
        </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Michael. Do you mind letting me know the reason for that?..  because the autocomplete belongs to a form with many other fields that i need to be there..

Comment: @JulioLopez In my experience, I usually use this pattern to handle the form. I feel that I have more control over my component. I can control what data field will be submitted without depending on a form. What happens when you want to use one of these data fields in other parts of your component before submitting it? If you have many other fields, you should set a value for these fields like the way I do with the ```AutoComplete``` component. You can use ```useReducer``` to store and manipulate your data fields if you have more than 3 fields in your form.

Comment: @wwwebman answer helped me.