# React, MUI AutoComplete and useState

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement AutoComplete component of MUI in React but i'm getting some errors, can't understand what am I doing wrong.

Those are the errors I get:

```
MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
None of the options match with `{"id":"2","name":"Stefanie","description":"I love her"}`.
You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.
```

This is my code:

```
function WomanAutoComplete(props) {

    const data = [
        {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Stefanie',
            description: 'I love her',
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            name: 'Jasmin',
            description: 'I miss her',
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            name: 'Angie',
            description: 'I hate her',
        }
    ];

    const defaultValue = { id: '1' };
    const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);

    const defaultProps = {
        options: data,
        getOptionLabel: (option) => option.name,
    };

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            {...defaultProps}
            id="grid-choose-woman"
            clearOnEscape
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                console.log(newValue);
                setValue(newValue);
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Woman" />
            )}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: let me ask you mui 4 or 5

Comment: latest one, so I guess it's 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use the default prop if you want to put value use the options={}  props to inject the values in to the ac component.

```js
< Autocomplete
options={data}
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
id = "grid-choose-pesticide"
clearOnEscape
defaultValue = {
  defaultValue
}

onChange = {
  (event, newValue) => {
    console.log(newValue);
    setValue(newValue);
  }
}
renderInput = {
  (params) => ( <
    TextField { ...params
    }
    label = "Pesticide" / >
  )
}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `isOptionEqualToValue` in your  element:

```
<Autocomplete
    {...defaultProps}
    id="grid-choose-pesticide"
    clearOnEscape
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        console.log(newValue);
        setValue(newValue);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Pesticide" />
    )}
    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
/>
```

The reason this happens is that the Autocomplete compares your selected object with a predefined one in the back.
You can see the full explanation in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65347275/5613027).